# How to install ruby on Debian6

Tags: ruby

after following the install instruction  [here](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) on my Debian system

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1
```

I still get the error

```
root@MyDebianVPS:/usr/local# ruby
bash: ruby: command not found
```

should I restart my system to make it work or I miss something?

```
$ su root
Password: 
root@MyDebianVPS:/home/yozloy# sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ruby1.9.1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
root@MyDebianVPS:/home/yozloy# ruby -v
bash: ruby: command not found
root@MyDebianVPS:/home/yozloy#
```

Comment: 1) Did the install finish properly? 2) Consider using RVM, it has many advantages and since it compiles Ruby from source, it might solve some incompatibility problems.

Comment: In debian sudo is not usually used. Rather try `su` instead, log in as root and then do `apt-get install ruby1.9.1`

Comment: @Bob I update some code for you guys to check out

Comment: Along the same lines as PJK's 2nd suggestion, consider using the rbenv and ruby-install libraries. They work great and are now considered superior to RVM.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks for letting me know rbenv, it's so cool, but I'm a newbie, and don't have the version conflict issue, so I want make it simple, a 1.9.2 working version is all I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to look to see if that is what the Debian package is actually called.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9
```

If that completes, awesome. Then try:

```
ruby -v
```

And report back what you have.

Comment: this actually gave me ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 1):

try `ruby1.9` ... they may not have symlinked the command to ruby.